# ASP NET, Xceed Docx, Table of content with heading that has no numbering

Tags: c#, asp.net, docx, xceed

In my C# ASP.NET code I have:

```
doc.InsertTableOfContents("Table of Contents", TableOfContentsSwitches.H);
```

Which results into [image: The title of TOC is numbered]

How can I insert the table of contents without the title being numbered, I ideally need something that would result into[image: The title of TOC is not numbered]

I tried to play around with the switches but unsucesfully, I tried to modify the Word settings when it comes to Headings or TOC but also unsucesfully

Answer (score 1):

The way I did it was by using this:

```
doc.InsertDefaultTableOfContents();
```

Then I added the content to it by adding the StyleId of a HeadingX to it. For example:

```
paragraph.StyleId = "Heading1";
```